# Windows Readfile return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87

Tags: c++, windows, readfile

My program creates a mailslot, but when I call ReadFile I get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

What about the parameter is wrong?

program code:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, NULL, false);

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor=&sd;
    sa.bInheritHandle=true;

    msg_id_ = CreateMailslot( msg_key_
                                , 0
                                , MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER
                                , &sa
                                );
```

`msg_id_` is not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` so this function succeeded.
`sa` should allow both `GENERIC_WRITE` and `GENERIC_READ`.

receiver code:

```
msg_id_ = CreateFile( msg_key_
                            , GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ
                            , FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ
                            , 0
                            , OPEN_EXISTING
                            , FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
                            , 0
                            );
ReadFile( msg_id_, (void*)msg, 1024, &byteLen, &ovRead);
```

The Readfile fails with error code ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Comment: Post more code. Are you checking the return value of CreateFile?

Comment: program code: createmailslot with MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER and sa. This is success. return values is not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the mailslot the wrong way around.

The mailslot *server* handle, created by calling `CreateMailslot`, is for *receiving* messages.

The mailslot *client* handle, created by calling `CreateFile`, is for *sending* messages.

You cannot call `ReadFile` with the client handle.  Mailslots are not bidirectional.